# How to clone an object and all related fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to clone an object instance and its related fields in Django.

I started writing a script:

```
from shop.models import Shop

shop = Shop.objects.get(pk=323232)
menus = shop.menu_set.all()
menu =  menus[0]
print menu.category_set.all()
```

I can see the category list, but I cannot iterate. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can see the category list, but I cannot iterate?"_

Comment: I can print the category_set.all() and see <Category:...> ...

Comment: what will happen if you start iterating menu.category_set.all()?

Comment: you should do `for cat in menu.category_set.all(): print menu`

Comment: It doesn't write anything in the shell